# Angular Chartjs error TS2304: Cannot find name OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, chart.js

I am using chartjs with Angular & Ionic:

installed:

- npm install chart.js --save

HTML

```
<!-- Graph -->
<div class="chart">
  <canvas #myChart></canvas>
</div>
```

TS

```
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';

Chart.register(...registerables);


const ctx = this.myChart.nativeElement;
this.chartHolder = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data,
  options
});
```

**Terminal ERROR**

```
ERROR in ../ node_modules / chart.js / types / index.esm.d.ts: 522: 5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D'.
522 | OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D

        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ./ node_modules / chart.js / types / index.esm.d.ts: 524: 5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvas'.
524 | OffscreenCanvas
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ./ node_modules / chart.js / types / index.esm.d.ts: 525: 35 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvas'.
525 | { canvas: HTMLCanvasElement | OffscreenCanvas }
                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ./ node_modules / chart.js / types / index.esm.d.ts: 526: 62 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvas'.
526 | ArrayLike<CanvasRenderingContext2D | HTMLCanvasElement | OffscreenCanvas>;
                                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ./ node_modules / chart.js / types / index.esm.d.ts: 3351: 66 - error TS2315: Type 'DeepPartial' is not generic.
3351 export type ScaleOptions<TScale extends ScaleType = ScaleType> = DeepPartial<ScaleOptionsByType<TScale>>;
                                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ./ node_modules / chart.js / types / index.esm.d.ts: 3365: 65 - error TS2315: Type 'DeepPartial' is not generic.
3365 export type ChartOptions<TType extends ChartType = ChartType> = DeepPartial<
                                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~
      3366   CoreChartOptions<TType> &
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         ...
      3371   ChartTypeRegistry[TType]['chartOptions']
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      3372 >;
```

Comment: use cdn for chartjs.  `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

I hope I can still help you and other people with this problem.

The `OffscreenCanvas` error is created because it is an experimental technology as stated in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas).

Therefore it is probable that errors, bugs, glitch, among others are created.
My suggestion from my own experience is in node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(500):

```
export declare type ChartItem =
  | string
  | CanvasRenderingContext2D
  // | OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D
  | HTMLCanvasElement
  // | OffscreenCanvas
  | { canvas: HTMLCanvasElement}// | OffscreenCanvas }
  | ArrayLike<CanvasRenderingContext2D | HTMLCanvasElement>;// | OffscreenCanvas>;
```

In the case of what happens with `DeepPartial` in my case what I did in `node_modules / chart.js / types / utils.d.ts` (13 and 14):

```
13  type _DeepPartialArray<T> = Array<Partial<T>>
14  type _DeepPartialObject<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: Partial<T[P]> };
```

what I did was change

```
Array<DeepPartial<T>>
```

to

```
Array<Partial<T>>
```

and

```
{[P in keyof T] ?: DeepPartial<T[P]>}
```

to

```
{[P in keyof T] ?: Partial<T[P]>}
```

Since a circular reference is being created with `DeepPartial` and that usually gives an error, my reference for this is in another language, but I will share it with you anyway

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMfvQLLqbzE&ab_channel=makigas%3Atutorialesdeprogramaci%C3%B3n

I'm using chart.js to create some charts with the MEAN Stack, it generated problems for me more than anything in compilation because the charts and the application still worked.

This is while a real solution comes out, since I have researched for almost a week and your question is the most accurate I have found on the entire internet that has exactly the same error, but still has no answer, I suppose because it is something very recent and that has not yet affected the mass, a true solution or correction of these errors has not come out.

Greetings!

Comment: This should be resolved in v3.6 of the lib since the offscreen canvas type has been removed from the typing

Answer (score 0):

Trying installing this as a dev dependency in your angular application

```
npm i @types/offscreencanvas --save-dev
```